# How to Countrows of repeating values across multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So I am trying to analyze the dataset above.
What I want to do is to count how movie fall in each genre.

Each animation has one column for genre.
In that "Genre" column has multiple values
so what I did was split that Genre column then I end up with 7 column for genres

[image]

```
Action = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        Animation_Movies, 
        Animation_Movies[Genre.1] = "Action" || 
        Animation_Movies[Genre.2] = "Action" || 
        Animation_Movies[Genre.3] = "Action" || 
        Animation_Movies[Genre.4] = "Action" || 
        Animation_Movies[Genre.5] = "Action" || 
        Animation_Movies[Genre.6] = "Action" || 
        Animation_Movies[Genre.7] = "Action"
    )
)
```

I used the query above to countrow
But it counts only the first genre column "Genre.1",
The idea is I want it to count "Action" in each column and combine the amount all together.

Please help
thank you

Comment: Can you share some of your data as text and not as an image ?

Comment: Data as text please that can be copy/pasted  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=For%20larger%20code%20snippets%2C%20you,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.)

Comment: Try this like to understand how pivot and unpivot can help on data manipulation.
https://youtu.be/u_oE3kauoYo?si=LN2hLOr6umli6ClS

Answer (score 1):

You'd rather unpivot these columns in Power Query so that you have one single column containing all genres. This is the shape Power Pivot is designed for.

=> This will make the DAX measure trivial and you'll be able to use some slicer, etc.